# Mocking a C# timer with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm attempting to create a WPF MVVM View Model that has a dependency injected `System.Timing.Timer`, and wish to test the view model with Moq.

I wrote a thin wrapper around the `Timer` class that has a interface `ITimer`, but am unsure of the best way to really test the timer's contribution to the class.  Is there a good way to 'force' a mock elapsed event? Does somebody else have a better technique?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495830/unit-testing-a-class-that-uses-a-timer) and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940982/how-can-i-run-the-event-handler-assigned-to-mock)

Comment: Thanks, I had done some googling around for that sort of thing, but had focused my queries on events in general rather than with timers, and couldn't find many good results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test your code in [isolation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestIsolation). Otherwise you don't know whether your code behaves as expected, or there is some side-effect in external dependency. Thus creating mockable wrappers for external resources (configuration files, timers, etc) is the only way you can separate your SUT from external code.

Comment: I know all about the concept of isolation, hence the tin mockable wrapper I wrote around `Timer`. I was more interested in techniques with mocking the events specifically. It seems that Ufuk's comment is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Raising event is simply calling some action on your model by mock. I don't see anything strange in this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework like `Moq` to trigger the event. You could also create a `FakeTimer` like so:

```
public class FakeTimer : IMyTimer
{
    private event ElapsedEventHandler elaspedHandler;
    private bool _enabled;

    public void Dispose() => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public FakeTimer(ElapsedEventHandler elapsedHandlerWhenTimeFinished, bool startImmediately)
    {
        this.elaspedHandler = elapsedHandlerWhenTimeFinished;
        _enabled = startImmediately;
    }

    public void Start() => _enabled = true;
    public void Stop() => _enabled = false;
    public void Reset() => _enabled = true;

    internal void TimeElapsed()
    {
        if (this._enabled)
            elaspedHandler.Invoke(this, new EventArgs() as ElapsedEventArgs);
    }
}
```

Where `TimeElapsed()` is what you would call in your unit tests to indicate that the time has passed.

It will then call off to the event associated with it.

In this example below, `MyCallBackMethod` would be called on `fakeTimer.TimeElapsed()`
`var fakeTimer = new FakeTimer(350, MyCallBackMethod, false)`